# How to align headers side by side for restaurant menu?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am building a website for a local restaurant and it's my first ever one. I am writing the menu out now but I do not know how to have for example Starters on one half of the screen and Main menu on the other half, side by side. I have also not been successful in making it responsive as when I make the screen smaller it gets very messy.

I have tried tinkering with bootstrap 4 using col-sm-6 but this didn't work for me. I also tried using flow and float in CSS but no luck.

```
<div class="menu-title">
      <h1>STARTERS</h1>
      <div class="menu-items">
        <div class="menu-item-body">
          <span class="number">1.</span>
          <span class="name">Vegetable Spring Roll</span>
          <span class="price">4.50&nbsp;€</span>
          <div class="description">
          Crispy spring roll with shredded cabbage, carrot, sweetcorn and soy sauce.                 
          </div>
        </div>                 
      </div>

      <div class="menu-items">
        <div class="menu-item-body">
          <span class="number">2.</span>
          <span class="name">Chicken Cheese Roll</span>
          <span class="price">4.50&nbsp;€</span>
          <div class="description">
          Crispy chicken cheese roll with chicken, onion, spring onion and cheese with sweet chilli sauce.                 
          </div>
        </div>                 
      </div>
```

CSS

```
.menu-title{
  flex-direction: column;
}


.menu-items {
  width: 100%; 
  padding: 50px 30px;
  flex-flow: row ;
}

.menu-item-body {
  float: left; 
  position: absolute;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin: 0 1%; 
  width: 31%; 
}
.number {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
.name {
  background-color: #fff; 
}

.name:after {
  float: left;
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  content: ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . " ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . " ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . " ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ";
}
.price {
  padding-left: 5px;
  float: right !important;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.description {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

I expect the output to be responsive and to show 2 or 3 columns of menu titles on a larger screen.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You've only included a portion of the code. I only see "starters", so I'm assuming the HTML is incomplete in your example. You need to edit the question to include a minimal version of what you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very simply with a media query and some simple floats and pseudo-selectors. It will allow you to stack the content in a normal flow by default (great for smaller viewports), but set containers side by side using floats and width values for larger viewports.

Here's an example of a simple float-based layout that allows for multiple parallel sections that respond well on multiple viewports. Here's [a CodePen demo of parallel sections with floats](https://codepen.io/denmch/pen/6785b4411acf2fdc585f8fc73fd77a19), followed by working code and an explanation:

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

.parent {
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

@media (min-width: 40em) {
  .parallel:not(:only-child)  {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
  }
  
  .parallel:nth-of-type(even) {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="parallel">
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Unde quaerat, quis hic quas earum officia numquam illum odio ipsa dolore accusamus, est expedita placeat autem sunt porro libero non ut.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="parallel">
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Unde quaerat, quis hic quas earum officia numquam illum odio ipsa dolore accusamus, est expedita placeat autem sunt porro libero non ut.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Unde quaerat, quis hic quas earum officia numquam illum odio ipsa dolore accusamus, est expedita placeat autem sunt porro libero non ut.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="parallel">
    <h2>Section 3</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Unde quaerat, quis hic quas earum officia numquam illum odio ipsa dolore accusamus, est expedita placeat autem sunt porro libero non ut.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Unde quaerat, quis hic quas earum officia numquam illum odio ipsa dolore accusamus, est expedita placeat autem sunt porro libero non ut.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Unde quaerat, quis hic quas earum officia numquam illum odio ipsa dolore accusamus, est expedita placeat autem sunt porro libero non ut.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Unde quaerat, quis hic quas earum officia numquam illum odio ipsa dolore accusamus, est expedita placeat autem sunt porro libero non ut.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="parallel">
    <h2>Section 4</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Unde quaerat, quis hic quas earum officia numquam illum odio ipsa dolore accusamus, est expedita placeat autem sunt porro libero non ut.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Unde quaerat, quis hic quas earum officia numquam illum odio ipsa dolore accusamus, est expedita placeat autem sunt porro libero non ut.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
<div class="parallel">
    <h2>Section 5 &#8212 Oops! No siblings!</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Unde quaerat, quis hic quas earum officia numquam illum odio ipsa dolore accusamus, est expedita placeat autem sunt porro libero non ut.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Even with sections of varying length, floats can handle the layout without resorting to advanced techniques or heavy markup by letting the content stay simple for smaller viewports and then adapt through a media query to run parallel on larger viewports.

A few of the tricks of the technique to make it run cleanly:

- `:not(:only-child)` allows you to apply the larger viewport split only if the parallel item has siblings within its row. This is just a useful catch in case a section needs to be in a row by itself or a sibling is temporarily removed. You don't need to tinker with the markup, but let CSS handle whether it splits the screen or not.
- Items that float left should clear both and items that float right should only clear right. This allows you to put several items in the same parent container and effect rows without added markup.
- To allow the sections to stagger rather than to align by row, you can remove `clear: both;` from the first selector in the media query. It will otherwise be the same.

There are other, more modern solutions, but this is good, easy, and flexible, with minimal markup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap Grid System and declare maximum container width.

For example:

`col-xl-12` - Extra Large screen = Full width.
`col-xl-4` - Extra Large screen = 1/3 screen width.

Look for my code: I created container, row, and finally declare grid options.

Check CodePen to see how it works on small devices.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/basicsindex/pen/GeLRRg)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-title {
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-items {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 30px;
  flex-flow: row ;
}

.menu-item-body {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
.number {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
.name {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.name:after {
  float: left;
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  content: ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . " ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . " ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . " ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ";
}
.price {
  padding-left: 5px;
  float: right !important;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.description {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="menu-title">
          <h1>STARTERS</h1>
          <div class="menu-items">
            <div class="menu-item-body">
              <span class="number">1.</span>
              <span class="name">Vegetable Spring Roll</span>
              <span class="price">4.50&nbsp;€</span>
              <div class="description">
                Crispy spring roll with shredded cabbage, carrot, sweetcorn and soy sauce.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="menu-items">
            <div class="menu-item-body">
              <span class="number">2.</span>
              <span class="name">Chicken Cheese Roll</span>
              <span class="price">4.50&nbsp;€</span>
              <div class="description">
                Crispy chicken cheese roll with chicken, onion, spring onion and cheese with sweet chilli sauce.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
        CENTER COLUMN CODE
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
        RIGHT COLUMN CODE
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a simple **Bootstrap 4** solution with a few custom styles just for presentation.

Basically you can use the `col-*` classes to structure the row how you want; of course; the issue you might have could be that you need each column to be for different types of items; so you can treat them as *rows*; you have the option to set `flex-column` so they behave more like you need; but some additional tweaks are necessary which I actually used on the second example using only Flexbox.

```css
.item {
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.item header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 item">
      <header>Item 1</header>
      <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti illum consectetur laborum sint sequi in hic dolore illo distinctio dolorum, earum quia dignissimos doloremque nesciunt deleniti nulla veritatis nemo nobis?</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 item">
      <header>Item 2</header>
      <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti illum consectetur laborum sint sequi in hic dolore illo distinctio dolorum, earum quia dignissimos doloremque nesciunt deleniti nulla veritatis nemo nobis?</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 item">
      <header>Item 3</header>
      <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti illum consectetur laborum sint sequi in hic dolore illo distinctio dolorum, earum quia dignissimos doloremque nesciunt deleniti nulla veritatis nemo nobis?</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 item">
      <header>Item 4</header>
      <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti illum consectetur laborum sint sequi in hic dolore illo distinctio dolorum, earum quia dignissimos doloremque nesciunt deleniti nulla veritatis nemo nobis?</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 item">
      <header>Item 5</header>
      <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti illum consectetur laborum sint sequi in hic dolore illo distinctio dolorum, earum quia dignissimos doloremque nesciunt deleniti nulla veritatis nemo nobis?</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 item">
      <header>Item 6</header>
      <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti illum consectetur laborum sint sequi in hic dolore illo distinctio dolorum, earum quia dignissimos doloremque nesciunt deleniti nulla veritatis nemo nobis?</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here you have a simple solution using only **Flexbox**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.item {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.menu-item {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.menu-item header {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap
  }
  .item {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    margin: 0 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="starters item">
    <h1>Starters</h1>
    <hr>

    <div class="menu-item">
      <header>Vegetable Spring Roll</header>
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit quam quo quaerat illum, vero numquam eligendi pariatur, est debitis voluptate dolores. Nesciunt doloremque cupiditate quo voluptatibus provident dicta iste ad?
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-item">
      <header>Chicken Cheese Roll</header>
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit quam quo quaerat illum, vero numquam eligendi pariatur, est debitis voluptate dolores. Nesciunt doloremque cupiditate quo voluptatibus provident dicta iste ad?
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-item">
      <header>Vegetable Spring Roll</header>
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit quam quo quaerat illum, vero numquam eligendi pariatur, est debitis voluptate dolores. Nesciunt doloremque cupiditate quo voluptatibus provident dicta iste ad?
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mains item">
    <h1>Mains</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="menu-item">
      <header>Chicken Cheese Roll</header>
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit quam quo quaerat illum, vero numquam eligendi pariatur, est debitis voluptate dolores. Nesciunt doloremque cupiditate quo voluptatibus provident dicta iste ad?
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-item">
      <header>Vegetable Spring Roll</header>
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit quam quo quaerat illum, vero numquam eligendi pariatur, est debitis voluptate dolores. Nesciunt doloremque cupiditate quo voluptatibus provident dicta iste ad?
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-item">
      <header>Chicken Cheese Roll</header>
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit quam quo quaerat illum, vero numquam eligendi pariatur, est debitis voluptate dolores. Nesciunt doloremque cupiditate quo voluptatibus provident dicta iste ad?
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```